# Cookie pop-up handle with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, popup

I tried to accept all cookies based on id but this is not working what can I do?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.geocaching.com/play")
driver.maximize_window()

cookie_allow = driver.find_element(By.ID, "CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept")
cookie_allow.click()

signin_link = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sign-in-link")
signin_link.click()
```

this is the html element: [html element screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtXSq.jpg)

Comment: Could you show the whole html with the element in it?

Comment: I attached the screenshot in the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Allow all")
```